# Betti numbers as characteristic numbers?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

Let $X$ be a compact differentiable manifold of dimension $m$ or, if you prefer, a smooth complex projective manifold of complex dimension $n=m/2$.

The Euler characteristic $\chi(X):=\Sigma_{i=0}^{m}(-1)^ib_i(X)$ -the alternating sum of Betti numbers of $X$- is related to the Euler class $e(T_X)$ of the tangent bundle $T_X$ by
$$\chi(X)=\int_Xe(T_X)$$
where $\int_X$ denotes contraction against the fundamental class $[X]$.

Is it possible to write each Betti number $b_i(X)$ as a "characteristic number", i.e. as an integral 
$$b_i(X)\stackrel{\text{?}}{=}\int_X\gamma_i(T_X)$$
of some "characteristic class" $\gamma_i$ of vector bundles? If not, why not?

This [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123913/chern-numbers-via-euler-characteristics) is possibly related.

Comment: Characteristic numbers are cobordism invariant, but Betti numbers are not.

Comment: By embedding a finite CW complex in Euclidean space,  thickening it up to a (framed) manifold, and taking its double, you can get any betti numbers but have trivial tangent bundle and hence trivial characteristic classes.

Answer (score 17):

No. The Stiefel-Whitney and Pontryagin numbers of a closed oriented manifold are cobordism invariants, but the Betti numbers are not.

More explicitly, all closed oriented $3$-manifolds are frameable (and null cobordant), so all of their characteristic numbers vanish, but e.g. the $3$-torus and $3$-sphere have different Betti numbers.